# "evaluator" vs "valuator" vs "rater"

Tags: word-choice, meaning

I'm looking for an English verb that describes an entity which gives a score/rating to something (a quality measure, for example). Would that be "evaluator", "valuator", "rater", or even something else? What are the exact semantic differences between these words?

**Edit:**

To clarify the context:

My problem is software development related: I'm looking for a name for a class that has the responsibility to give certain objects of another class a rating. The objects describe schedules for employees, and these schedules should get a score with regards to certain objectives ("how well does the schedule respect the desired working hours", "how well does it cover the workload", ...) .

Comment: I think your question is a bit too broad, or vague. You can take your question multiple ways, and that will give you different answers depending on the context. For example, people may see this question as if you're looking for the term describing "somebody who rates products and attaches an estimated price" which would be an appraiser. If you were looking for "somebody who looks at publications, like books and movies and shares their own opinion" that would be a reviewer or critic. I'd suggest giving us a bit more context, and edit your question as well.

Comment: @shadowmanwkp: I've added some additional information.

Comment: I have to feel sorry for the poor poster! One person says that he should specify the context in which he's asking the question. So he edits his question to include context, and then someone else says that this context is out of bounds and deletes the update! What's he supposed to do?

Comment: @Matt: I second Jay's comment. The O.P. wasn't asking for a variable name; the O.P. asked for a verb, but then mentioned that the reason he was looking for that verb was to help with a class name. Though the difference is subtle, I believe this question is much worse now that the edit has been removed, and I never felt like it was asking for a variable name, even after the edit was made.

Comment: You should probably use two or more words in the name to be more descriptive: ‘Working Hours Assessor’ or ‘Workload Evaluator’ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a vague question...from the context you give I personally would use one of:

> **Assessor**
>
> **Scorer**
>
> **Evaluator**

Comment: Note that "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is specifically named as off-topic for ELL/ELU: english.stackexchange.com/faq. I've edited your question to be only about English and not about programming, since good variable/function/class names are not necessarily good English and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word *rater*; the [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rater) defines rater as:

> **rater** *noun*
>
> 1 a person or instrument that rates something
> 2 an instrument that rates something

Another possibility would be *analyzer*. Even though the word analyze by itself doesn't necessarily result in a score, that could still be inferred by the context of the application.